# multiprocessing numpy not defined error

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pathos

I am using the following test code:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
import numpy

def foo(obj1, obj2):
   a = obj1**2
   b = numpy.asarray(range(1,5))
   return obj1, b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    res = p.map(foo, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

It gives error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Edit: Why was this question voted down twice?

I have numpy installed and my interpreter has been using it correctly until I try to do it for multiprocessing. I have been coding with same install for a while.

Comment: Please make sure you have numpy installed. If your answer is yes: Make sure you've installed it for the Python you're actually using. If your answer is yes: Try the `import numpy` inside your `foo` function. I think the question was downvoted because google returns a lot of answers if you ask it about your error.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have seen my edit to the comment. Maybe pathos doesn't know you imported numpy. Maybe you should put the `import numpy` inside your `foo` function.

Comment: How do I resolve this problem as for my real life example I have to import more than 10 packages and I can't be doing that in the function or is that the only way?

Comment: does it work when you import it inside the function?

Comment: Yes it works when I do import inside the function.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like imports are not shared between processes. Therefore you need to `import numpy` in all your processes seperatly.

In your case this means adding the `import numpy` in your `foo` function. Processes are not light-weight so the `import` won't slow you down (at least not significantly).

The other alternative would be to pass the module to the functions (not recommended and I'm not sure if that will work):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    res = p.map(foo, numpy, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])

def foo(np, obj1, obj2):
   a = obj1**2
   b = np.asarray(range(1,5))
   return obj1, b
```